How do I programmatically add phonetic guides to cells using VBA for Excel?
I have a list of japanese vocab consisting of Kanji and Kana.
I am trying to make my life easier so I don't have to manually click every cell and click "edit phonetics", just so Excel auto inserts the Furigana above the Kanji.
I want to create a VBA script such that, either with the click of a button, or automatically upon enabling the phonetic guides, it will auto populate the Furigana.
I suspect Excel uses a built-in function to convert the Kanji to Furigana, since I just copied the raw Kanji from the internet and Excel converts it after I click "edit phonetics" and exit out again.
I looked for other solutions to this problem and I found this:
Sub PhoneticGuide()
    Selection.Range.PhoneticGuide Text:="tray sheek", _
     Alignment:=wdPhoneticGuideAlignmentCenter, _
     Raise:=11, FontSize:=7
End Sub

source: How to edit a MS Word system macro
However, I do not understand how to use it for my purposes.
